# Safecopy a whole directory

Tags: safecopy

[Safecopy](http://safecopy.sourceforge.net/) can rescue a file or a partition from a failing hard drive. But what if you want to rescue a whole directory? It doesn't look like there's a way to do this in safecopy.

Is there a command that will run safecopy, recusrively, on every individual file in a directory, and put it in the appropriate place on the rescued media?

I have a huge, failing drive but I only need to rescue one directory from it.

Comment: That can be easily done. But you should provide an example directory structure with the necessary command lines for Safecopy because I am not familiar with it (as probably others, too) and don't want to have to learn first how this program works.

Comment: OK, to rescue a file from a damaged hard drive with safecopy, you run this command: safecopy /path/to/problemfile ~/saved-file. In my case, the folder would be media/brokendrive/Users/bill/Documents/ and I would be rescuing to /media/newdrive/billrescue/. In the old drive are folders like /photos, /contracts, and so on. I would want the structure to be the same on the new drive.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use this tool to recover an entire filesystem partition from the bad hard drive to a working medium, and then get the individual files and directories from the recovery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Safecopy creates the missing directories in the target path thus we create them first:

```
cd /media/newdrive/billrescue
find /media/brokendrive/Users/bill/Documents -type d -printf "%P\0" |
    xargs -0 echo mkdir -p
```

Now we call `safecopy` once for every file:

```
cd media/brokendrive/Users/bill/Documents
find . -type f -exec echo safecopy {} /media/newdrive/billrescue/{} \; | head
```

Remove the `echo` and the `| head` if the output is what you need.

Or:

```
find /media/brokendrive/Users/bill/Documents -type f -printf "%P\0" |
    xargs -0 -I{} echo safecopy /media/brokendrive/Users/bill/Documents/{} /media/newdrive/billrescue/{}
```